# Can I use a max-width for content but full-width for background?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a Wordpress-theme with a theme-options page. In these options, a max-width for the website can be set, but I'm having some difficulties with the content-area.

When the `max-width` is filled in, the header- and footer-area get the `max-width` and a `margin: O auto;`.

The content-pages will be created using the Gutenberg Builder and I want to be able to add background-attributes to the blocks I use and display them full-width, but the content to fall into the max-width which was defined before.

HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
   <div class="header-wrapper"></div>
</header>
<main class="site-content">
   <article class="post-10">
      <header></header>
      <div></div>
      <footer></footer
   </article>
</main>
<footer class="site-footer">
   <div class="header-wrapper"></div>
</footer
```

CSS:

```
.header-wrapper,
.footer-wrapper,
article {
     max-width: 1366px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I get this:
[image: This is how it looks now]

I want my background to be full-width, but my content to have the same with as the content of my header and footer.

Is there a possibility to set the same `max-width` for the header-, content- and footer-section of the page, and make sure the background in the content-area is still full-width?

Comment: what is your css?

Comment: Either try this approach, https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ - or make sure to apply your width limit only to the children of whatever element actually gets the “block background” assigned.

Comment: I added my css and some more details. I don't really know how to do it because the content-blocks in the site-content area will be different on every page.

Comment: One problem is that the max-width is set dynamically, so it can be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate "wide alignment" and "full alignment" by adding `add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );`
 to your functions.php file. The user then has the option to align *images* across the whole viewport width.

See also https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/themes/theme-support/#opt-in-features

But that's for images, not for backgrounds.

For background areas/images you could try to create regular blocks (100% of the content area) which have margin settings like `margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%); margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);` (same as in full-width Gutenberg blocks) and padding-left/padding-right `calc(50vw - 50%);`: That way the block would span the whole viewport width, but the content area would have the width of the content area (full width minus padding). You also would have to add the regular padding you want to use inside your content column to those values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand then your css should look like this:

```
.header-wrapper,
.footer-wrapper,
article header, article div, article footer {
     max-width: 1366px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
article{
     width: 100%;
     background: blue;
}
```

but only if `max-width` is setted for those 3 divs inside article

Does `content-block` is represented by `article` ?

**Update**

I recreated codepen from https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eaJyqV

If this is possible you could put image with `position: absolute` and then put text with `position: absolute` on top of it but I guess your content-block doesnt work that way ;/

Comment: The actual content of my page sits in the div inside the article. This div could include multiple blocks, so I want the background of these blocks full-width, but the content only 1366px

Comment: @ThessaVerbruggen oh I understand. if this multiple blocks has common class then I guess 04FS comment(your post) should be your answer

Comment: @ThessaVerbruggen nah there will be problem with height of background ;/